# Set problem. Is it possible to find out the value of four variables in three queries?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

There are four variables. Each variable stores a value. Think of it like a dictionary.
The values don't have to be unique.

Is it possible to find out the value of all variables in three queries? Each query can be thought of as a function: $query(variables)$ return values in **ascending order without being bound to a variable.**

For example, if variables $A=2, B=1, C=1, D=2$, then $query(D,B)$ return $1,2$. That is, according to the return values of the function, it is impossible to establish the belonging of a variable. Because the function sorts the values. The only option when it is possible to do it $query(A)$. Such a query will definitely return the value of variable $A$.

I did something like that:

1. $query(A,B,C,D)$
2. $query(A,B,C)$
3. $query(B,C)$

This gives the following (as a difference of sets):

$query_1-query_2 = D$

$query_2-query_3=A$

But to calculate the remaining two values, it seems that only three queries are missing. Is it so?

Comment: I do not understand the question or the constraints on queries. Are query(X) pairwise distinct? Can you try to reformulate the question, the goal, the problem and what you are allowed to do?

Comment: Also, can we design the queries adaptively, based on the result of a previous query?

Comment: Looks like $(A,B), (C,D), (B,C)$ does the trick. At least if all values are distinct.

Comment: @user58697 (A,B),(C,D),(B,C) almost works but can't distinguish between patterns of the form (A,B,C,D) = (x,y,x,y) and (y,x,y,x)

Answer (score 1):

(A,B,C), (A,B,D), (B,C,D) works whether or not the values are distinct. A bit of Python to verify:

```
from itertools import product

# this one  produces 256 distinct results
results = set()
n=0
for a,b,c,d in product([1,2,3,4],repeat=4):
  #print (a,b,c,d)
  s1 =  tuple(sorted( (a,b,c) ))
  s2 =  tuple(sorted( (a,b,d) ))
  s3 =  tuple(sorted( (d,b,c) ))
  results.add( (s1,s2,s3) )
  n+=1

print (len(results), n)  
  
  
# this one only produces 250 distinct results
results = set()
n=0
for a,b,c,d in product([1,2,3,4],repeat=4):
  #print (a,b,c,d)
  s1 = tuple(sorted( (a,b) ))
  s2 =  tuple(sorted( (c,d) ))
  s3 =  tuple(sorted( (b,c) ))
  results.add( (s1,s2,s3) )
  n+=1

print (len(results), n)
```

Late edit: Additionally  (A,B), (A,C), (B,C,D) works. I think these are the only two patterns that work.